# When starting a project for debugging, why does Visual Studio build the whole solution and not just the project?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging

In Visual Studio, if you select "Start Debugging" or "Start Without Debugging" to run the currently selected startup project, Visual Studio always builds the entire solution. This seems unnecessary, as all it really needs to do is build the project you wish to start, and its dependents.

If you have some unit tests projects for example, you can't run the startup project until all of your unit test projects also compile. At the very least, it is a waste of time building all of these unit test projects as the project one wishes to run will not be dependent on them anyway.

Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can change this behaviour (and I always do, for the exact reasons you describe).

Go to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run`. then check "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run".

Comment: FYI In Visual Studio 2012 RTM this is now checked by default.

Comment: Actually, I just found out me and some of my colleagues had this unchecked on VS 2012. Probably since VS installation, as none of us does remember doing anything with this setting.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was already checked but was still not building. VS 2012 was only building the main (start up) project but none of its dependencies. It found that it was because of the `Active configuration` in the `ConfigurationManager` was set to build only the Main (start up) project.

Go to `Build` > `ConfigurationManager`

Ensure that all the projects you want to build are checked as in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question asked.